# With arangodb AQB how do you get out/inEdges an from/toVertices? in a query?

Tags: arangodb, graph-traversal

Suppose the following query from `fluent query interface`  thats removed as of `v3.x`:

```
var tens = graph._vertices(lst).outEdges().restrict("knows").toVertices()
.inEdges().restrict("works").fromVertices().inEdges().restrict("owns")
.fromVertices().toArray();
```

here `lst` is a simply a list of vertices obtained from a prior query, 
and the vertices in `lst` may have outgoing edge relationships one of which 
is of type `knows`, and the vertices pointed to by these outEdges have incoming edges of type `works` in turn,

how would this be written with AQB? the two (AQB and `fluent query interface` are supposed to overlap and thats why one was removed).
Iv looked at the documentation [on github](https://github.com/arangodb/aqbjs) but im not seeing anything that would help with a query like the one above

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have worked out so far:

```
db._query("FOR vrt0 in @lst FOR vrt1  in OUTBOUND vrt0 knows FOR vrt2 in 
INBOUND vrt1 works  FOR vrt3 in INBOUND vrt2 owns RETURN vtr3",{"@lst": lst });
```

The information retrieved is equivalent to what i would expect from the corresponding `fluent query interface`.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that this can't be represented in AQB. We're currently in the process of deprecating AQB in favour of the `aql` template handler supported by both the JavaScript driver (arangojs) and ArangoDB 2.8 and later: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/javascript-api/@arangodb/#the-aql-template-tag

With the template string handler it is possible to write arbitrary AQL queries in ArangoDB 3. If I understand it correctly, your fluent query should translate to something like this:

```
db._query(aql`
  FOR vertex IN ${lst}
  FOR v1 IN OUTBOUND vertex knows
  FOR v2 IN INBOUND v1 works
  FOR v3 IN INBOUND v2 owns
  RETURN v3
`).toArray()
```